# How to write an expression to display percentage values along with legend values pie chart using RDLC

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am generating report using RDLC. How to write an expression to display percentage values along with legend values pie chart using RDLC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=Fields!grp.Value & ": " & "#PERCENT{P2}"
```

Comment: Thank u so much. That really helped.